# give different color to clicked link and restore its color when other links are clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hyperlink

I have a top nav links that drive links in the left nav. The top nav contains a bunch of topics. Each topic link when clicked populates left nav with related links on the topic. So when a topic on the top nav is clicked i want it to change its color to like red while the rest are blue, but as soon as another title is clicked, i want the previously clicked link to restore its color back to blue and the newly clicked one to gain the red color. How can we do this in jquery? Adding classes and removing classes and using css is not working.. please help..

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>MY C# Notes</title>     
    <style type="text/css">
    body,
    html {margin:0; padding:0;color:#000;background:#a7a09a;}
    #wrap {width:1050px;margin:0 auto;background:#99c;}
    #header {padding:5px 10px;background:#ddd;}
    h1 {margin:0;}
    #nav {padding:5px 10px;background:#c99;}
    #nav ul {margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;}
    #nav li {display:inline;margin:0;padding-right:15px;}
    #main { float:right;width:780px;padding:10px;background:#9c9;min-height:600px;}
    h2 {margin:0 0 1em;}
    #sidebar {float:left;width:230px;padding:10px;background:#99c;min-height:600px;}
    #footer {clear:both;padding:5px 10px;background:#cc9;}
    #footer p { margin:0;  }
    * html #footer {height:1px;}
    .high{color:red}
    a.loader { color: blue; }    
    </style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {   
$('a.loader').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
    $('#sidebar').load($(this).attr('href'));
            $("a.loader").removeClass("high");
            $(this).addClass("high");});
});

</script>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="header"><h1>My C# Notes and Exercises</h1></div>
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="loader" href="topic1.html">Topic1</a></li>
            <li><a class="loader" href="topic2.html">Topic2</a></li>
            <li><a class="loader" href="topic3.html">Topic3</a></li>
            <li><a class="loader" href="topic4.html">Topic4</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">LocalBrowser</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>C# Online Tutorials</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$(function() {});` is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function() {});`, so you are setting a `document.ready` event handler in document.ready. I haven't check this in any browsers yet, but something tells me that that will only cause you problems. Try removing either of those (and its corresponding `});`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css class `.loader` is getting priority over `.high`; you can fix this by:

-adding `!important` to the declaration for `.high`: `.high {color: red !important;}`

-swapping the order of the declarations in your css: `a.loader { color: blue;} a.high { color: red; }`

-or removing `.loader` when you add `.high`:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('a.loader').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#sidebar').load($(this).attr('href'));
        $("a.high").not(this).removeClass("high").addClass('loader');
        $(this).removeClass('loader').addClass("high");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Very well explained!

Answer (score 1):

The blue from the loader class is overwriting the red so use this:

```
.high{color:red !important}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AZqUx/

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you have two relevant CSS rules here:

```
a.loader { color: blue; }    
.high { color: red; }
```

One of the most important principals of CSS is that more specific rules will override less specific ones. Of the above 2 rules, the first applies to all `<a>` elements with class `loader`, and the second applies to all elements with class `high`. Since the first is more specific (includes a tag as well as class description), it is given priority and overrides the `color: red;` from the other rule. The easiest way to be fix this would be to make your second rule more specific:

```
a.loader { color: blue; }    
a.high { color: red; }
```

Since the rule for `a.high` is declared later, it will be given priority. However, you can future-proof this a bit better by actually making the second rule more specific than the first. Assuming you only need this to work in child elements of the `<div id="nav">` element, you can do this:

```
a.loader { color: blue; }    
#nav a.high { color: red; }
```

This you can move both declarations around freely and not get any unexpected behavioral change. You find [the CSS specificity rules](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/) helpful if you have any questions about why this works. :D

Comment: Very informative, thank you! I had to choose @nbrooks answer as he also  included a jquery fix. Thank you again!